# find width of the image using JavaScript, while image added as background-image in css

Tags: javascript, css

have to find the image natural width, heigth

but image added form **css** as a **`background-image`**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.image {
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=0');
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kj8nmyxv/)

Comment: Maybe (img=new Image()).src="sth";img.naturalWidth ...

Comment: @Jonasw yeah trying that but not going as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments:

```js
// Get the image
var img = document.querySelector(".image");
// Get its current style
var style = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(img) : img.currentStyle;
// Extract the URL from it
var match = /url\("?([^")]+)"?\)/.exec(style.backgroundImage);
if (match) {
  // Create an `img`
  var x = document.createElement('img');
  // Watch for when it loads (it'll presumably come from cache)
  x.onload = function() {
    // Now we know its natural size
    console.log("width = " + x.width + ", height = " + x.height);
    console.log("naturalWidth = " + x.naturalWidth + ", naturalHeight = " + x.naturalHeight);
  };
  // Set the src (AFTER hooking 'load')
  x.src = match[1];
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.image {
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=0');
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Details on the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/7DyTrt/1). Basically, it extracts the path within the `url(...)` omitting `"`s.

Of course, if you don't have to get the URL from the element's `background-image`, all the better...

Comment: `match = /url\("?([^")]+)"?\)/.exec(style.backgroundImage);` is there an other way, i am getting an error like this .. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kj8nmyxv/)

Comment: @bhv: That fiddle doesn't use the working code above. My suggestion is...use the working code above instead. ;-) (The reason for the error is that you're not removing the quotes around the value.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attribute value using jQuery like this

var  image_width = $(".image").width());
var  image_height = $(".image").height());

I am posting this from my phone so forgive the in formatted code